# Hibernate-Spring @Transactional behavior

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a @Transactional method that calls another @Transactional method. The child method deletes all the table and the parent stores new rows so I want that if I have an exception in the parent method, the database does the rollback (both methods in the same transaction). I read in the documentation that for default this tag is Propagration.REQUIRED but the behavior I have is that even if I have an exception in the parent, the table is cleared.

This is the parent:

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public boolean cleanAndStoreCmsTableDao (List<MaintenanceMessage> list) throws Exception {
    for(MaintenanceMessage mm : list) {
        cmsTableDao.deleteMm(mm.getMm_id()); // The child is called
    }
    File file = new File(path);
    cmsTableDao.storePreviousCMSTable(file);
    return CmsTableCsvParser.parseCVSFile(path,cmsTableDao); // THIS METHOD PRODUCES AN EXCEPTION!!!
}
```

This is the child (another class)

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public boolean deleteMm(String mm_id) {
    deleteById(MaintenanceMessage.class, mm_id);
    return true;
}
```

PD: In both I am using org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional not JPA's version.

Comment: Don't you have AUTOCOMMIT = ON somewhere?

Comment: No I didn't activated autocommit, but are there any method in java or Java Hiberbate config to disable it to be sure? I tried "prop.put("hibernate.connection.autocommit", "false");" but the result is the same

Comment: I would also check how the class with cleanAndStoreCmsTableDao () is created. Is it really proxied?